# Show $f(x) >0$ for $x>x_0$ if its $f' >f$ and $f(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Suppose that $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0 \in R$. Prove that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>x_0$. As an application of this, show that  $ae^x=a+x+x^2/2$.

Here is my attempt: 
We know that $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}-f(x)\geq 0$. So let $x=x_o+h$, $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}}-f(x_0)\geq 0$. So  $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+h)}{h}}\geq 0$. And I'm stuck.

Comment: You can use strict inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed by contradiction. First since $f'(x_0) > f(x_0) = 0$, there is some $t > 0$ s.t. $f (x)>0$ on $(x_0, x_0+t)$. Assume $f(x) \leqslant 0$ for some $z > x_0$, and $z$ is the minimal one, i.e. $f(y) >0$ when $x_0 < y < z$, hence $f'(y) >0$ on $(x_0, z)$ as well, and by the MVT, $f(z) > f(x_0) = 0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part: let $g(x) = e^{-x}{f(x)}$ and let $x > x_0$. By the MVT there exists $c \in (x_0, x)$ such that
$$
g(x) - g(x_0) = g'(c) (x-x_0)
$$
i.e.
$$
e^{-x}{f(x)} - e^{-x_0}{f(x_0)} = e^{-c}[f'(c) - f(c)] (x-x_0) > 0
$$
so that $e^{-x}f(x) > 0$, i.e. $f(x) > 0$.

Comment: Problem doesn't say $f'>0$ so we don't know a priori that $f'(c)>0$

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the answer.